# while installing cypress through command :npm install cypress --save-dev getting error as The Cypress App could not be downloaded

Tags: npm-install, cypress

while installing cypress through command :npm install cypress --save-dev getting error as The Cypress App could not be downloaded.
Error :
Finishing Installation
The Cypress App could not be downloaded.

Does your workplace require a proxy to be used to access the Internet? If so, you must configure the HTTP_PROXY environment variable before downloading Cypress. Read more: https://on.cypress.io/proxy-configuration

Otherwise, please check network connectivity and try again:

But please not I m not using any proxy and on  my personal wifi.
plz suggest ,what can  be done in this case.Thanks

Answer (score 10):

It seems to be too many possible reasons for this issue in general but I managed to find a workaround to install Cypress from within a corporation with npm and without using sudo npm or turning off strict ssl.

The following worked for me per November 18th 2020 with Ubuntu 18.04 and npm 6.14.8:

1. I downloaded the zip file shown in https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Direct-download
2. I installed cypress as shown in https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Install-binary : `CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=~/Downloads/cypress.zip npm install cypress --save-dev`
3. I could now run `npx cypress open` to start the gui (which will also generate the cypress.json file)

Answer (score 0):

Possible Reasons for this issue:

1. U might be running the project with a proxy setting.
2. One of the reason could be you are behind the firewall.that may prohibit your network? Please follow the guidelines in Proxy Configuration if so(https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration.html#Set-a-proxy-on-Linux-or-macOS).
3. make sure you have right access to install the cypress.
4. if none of the above mentioned reasons try removing the biraries or node_modules and install again.